# Estimating integral of $\frac{\log z}{z^2+a^2}$ over small upper-plane semi-circle

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to calculate $$\int^\infty_0{\frac{\log z}{z^2+a^2}\mathrm{d}z}$$

I was able to calculate this using residue calculus and different half-plane and full keyhole contours, but have not been able to nail down an approximation of the inner semi-circle (or inner circle, depending on the contour) as the radius goes to zeros to show that the integral on the inner semi-circle goes to zero.

The usual upper bound using the length of the curve and the maximum of the norm of the integrand didn't work in my mind. I also tried writing the integral over $[0, \pi]$ but did not get any insights from that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that we have for $a>\varepsilon$, $|\varepsilon^2e^{i2\phi}+a^2|\ge a^2 -\varepsilon^2$ and

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \frac{2\pi \varepsilon \log^2(\varepsilon)}{a^2-\varepsilon^2} =0 $$

Comment: Whoops, that was far easier than I thought - thanks!